# Open the keyboard immediately

Tags: android, keyboard

There are two methods: `showSystemKeyboard` and`hideSystemKeyboard`. I think everything is logical, one method reveals the keypad, the other hides it.

keyboard display method call in `showSystemKeyboard` onStart () method:

```
@Override
    public void onStart () {
        super.onStart ();
        if (allAvailableTags.isEmpty () && selectedTags.isEmpty ()) {
            Utils.showSystemKeyboard (tagNameInputView);
        }
    }
```

The method itself `showSystemKeyboard`:

```
public static void showSystemKeyboard (EditText view) {
        if (view! = null) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService (Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.showSoftInput (view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    }
```

The challenge is that when you call the dialog in my class TagDialog, where the method is implemented onStart () keyboard is opened immediately. Say at once SHOW_FORCED constant once is not suitable.

I try this method:

```
tagNameInputView.requestFocus();
    tagNameInputView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (allAvailableTags.isEmpty() && selectedTags.isEmpty()) {
                InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                keyboard.showSoftInput(tagNameInputView, 0);
            }
        }
    },200);

    tagNameInputView.requestFocus();
    tagNameInputView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            keyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(tagNameInputView.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    },200);
```

But I still need to click on the field EditText, before open the keyboard(

Comment: do you want the keyboard  or no?

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">  did you add this in your Manifest Activity file?

Comment: OP, Why was this tagged `java` when it's relevant only for `android` ?

Comment: @AnuragJoshi i have a keyboard. I need to open it as soon as you opened my dialog. But the keyboard is opened only after I clicked on my EditText(tagNameInputView).

Comment: can you show your onClick method for tagNameInputView